# Return mongodb dynamic attributes in graphql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, graphql, mongoid

I have the following graphql type

```
class Types::UserListType < Types::BaseObject
  field :id, ID, null: false
  field :name, String, null: false
  field :email, String, null: false
end
```

Now I have added a new attribute, custom_attributes, in the user table which is stored as a Hash in mongoid. It will have dynamic key/value pairs in the database. How do I return this data back in the graphql query for users.

Looking for something like this,

```
class Types::UserListType < Types::BaseObject
  field :id, ID, null: false
  field :name, String, null: false
  field :email, String, null: false
  field :custom_attributes, Hash, null: true
end
```

How do I even do something like this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Sunil did you manage to do this?